# Calendar in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to build a webpage that has calendars of the next 6 months (including current month).

The user can look at the calenders and click on a day, to link to a booking form.

Is this possible using ASP.NET?

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes; that is possible.  Just make a giant table.

Comment: Yes it is... Start implementing your calendar and if you have any trouble post some code and we'll help...

Comment: Agree with the above comments.  However, you may wish to look at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ as a possibility

Comment: Are there any other requirements that you're thinking of, that might make it complicated?  It sounds relatively simple.